# Crash reporter for programs distributed as source?

Tags: c++, crash-reports, crash-dumps

I'm interested in adding a crash reporter to our program. The difficulty is that in the typical case our program is distributed as source, which the user then compiles themselves.

Typical crash reporting systems like core dumps and Google Breakpad assume that the developers have access to binaries identical to those which generated the crash report. (For example, Breakpad minidumps don't have any symbol information, and rely on a symbol table that has been generated on the developers' side.) This is not necessarily going to be the case if the user has compiled the software on their own machine. (Due to different OS variants, different compilers, etc.)

Is there a robust, cross-platform crash reporting system, one which doesn't depend on the developer having a binary-identical version of the program on hand? *(Cross platform for us is primarily Unix-like (Linux and MacOS), though something that would work for Windows too would be appreciated.)*

I've looked into putting together an *ad hoc* reporter with backtrace/backtrace_symbols/__cxa_demangle, but that only gives the call tree at best. I'm wondering if it's possible to also get information about the contents of local variables - particularly the value of the parameters passed to the functions.

Comment: You're asking the impossible.   You're essentially asking for a "crash reporter" to report information about code it knows nothing about (since it was written by a "user") without accessing any information at all about that code (which is what a "binary-identical version of the program" contains).

Comment: @Peter It's not user-written code, it's our code that the user compiled. And the crash reporter, running on the user's system, has access to the binary on the user's system; it's just the devels which don't have access to a bit-for-bit identical copy of the complied binary. (We have the code and can compile it ourselves, but the layout won't necessarily be the same.) -- What I ask is not theoretically impossible: a debugger can do similar things, and things like backtrace/backtrace_symbols works even in the absence of a debugger. Is it *practically* possible? I don't know; that's why I asked.

Comment: If you're talking specifically about **Windows**, there's noting stopping you from writing your own _Unhandled Exception Filter_.

Comment: If the user compiles himself, why shouldn't he have symbols? They will be generated on his machine. Why not use them?

Comment: @ThomasWeller If you're referring to Breakpad, that's just the way it works (AFAICT). It's set up under the assumption that users are obtaining (stripped) binaries from the developers. As such, it doesn't include any symbolic information in the reports it sends back. -- If you're referring to the rest of my post, I agree. My question is *how* one would do that.